# Finding the URL for New Item Form - several content types

Tags: content-type, form

I am attempting to find the URL for the form to add new items to the list.  I have several content types being used and would like to find the URL for each of the content types.

On a side note, I noticed that after creating an item, the edit form includes a drop-down list for changing the content type.  This drop-down list does not exist on the new item form.  Is there a way to include that?  if so, it would negate my issue above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists with multiple content types use one default NewForm. The fields are rendered dynamically by passing in the appropriate content type ID in the query string, `&ContentTypeId=0x0100E2C13416E29ACD4DB77D24CABE7CE08F`, for example.

The easiest way to find that is to disable forms from opening in modals for the list, if in 2010. If in 2007 still, it's visible in the URL.